# Left and Right Carousel Controls not Working when Smooth Scroll for Anchor Tags Used

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

I am using the following script for smooth scroll effect for anchor tags:

```
$(function() {
  $('a[href*=#]:not([href=#])').click(function() {
    if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {
      var target = $(this.hash);
      target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');
      if (target.length) {
        $('html,body').animate({
          scrollTop: target.offset().top
        }, 1000);
        return false;
      }
    }
  });
});
```

After using this script the Left and Right controls for Bootstrap Carousel stopped working.

```
<a class="left carousel-control" href="#home-carousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
            </a>
            <a class="right carousel-control" href="#home-carousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
            </a>
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: For what anchor tags are you using the smooth scroll effect, any or just a menu?

Comment: @brance Just the menu

Comment: Do you have a id for your menu div, like #menu or something similar?

Comment: Yes. I am using the header-menu tag for it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Then you just have to edit you code for the smooth scroll like this, depending if you have the ID `header-menu` or class `header-menu`

Change

```
$('a[href*=#]:not([href=#])').click(function() {
```

to (if you use the ID header-menu)

```
$('#header-menu a[href*=#]:not([href=#])').click(function() {
```

or (if you use the class header-menu):

```
$('.header-menu a[href*=#]:not([href=#])').click(function() {
```

This way you will only focus the smooth scroll effect on the menu href elements, and the script will not "collide" with you bootstrap hrefs.